# Ubuntu 18.04.1 booting error Hyper-V

Tags: boot, 18.04, hyper-v

Error appears only when booting with Linux 4.15.0-44.
With 4.15.0-29 works good.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same trouble here with Xubuntu 18.04 LTS in Hyper-V after (automatically) updating to Kernel 4.15.0.45 Stefan's fix of reverting to a Kernel before 4.15.0.44 worked for me as well, on two different Virtual Machines. (would have commented, rep not there yet though)

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly the same error. with Ubuntu 18.04 in the Hyper-V Environment on kernel 4.15.0.44.

Replacing it with the previous Kernel version 4.15.0.**43** solved the problem.